# Finally, what is the fastest way to iterate trough pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance

Regarding the above question, there are many posts on SO as well as many articles on the internet. I've read a lot of them and combined my findings to test some best practices to figure out the fastest way to iterate through Pandas dataframes. Although choosing the best method depends on what you're going to do with your data, I chose a simple operation of summing two columns from a sample dataframe for this test.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
import time

B = []
t = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(0, 10000), 'b': range(10000, 20000)})
for _ in range(50):
    A = time.time()
    C = (t['a'].to_numpy() + t['b'].to_numpy()).tolist()
    B.append({"method": "1- vectorizing + to_numpy", "time": time.time()-A})

    A = time.time()
    C = (t['a'] + t['b']).tolist()
    B.append({"method": "2- vectorizing", "time": time.time()-A})

    C = []
    A = time.time()
    for r in zip(*t.to_dict("list").values()):
        C.append((r[0] + r[1]))
    B.append({"method": "3- zip + to_dict('list')", "time": time.time()-A})

    C = []
    A = time.time()
    for r in zip(t['a'], t['b']):
        C.append((r[0] + r[1]))
    B.append({"method": "4- zip", "time": time.time()-A})

    C = []
    A = time.time()
    for ir in t.itertuples(name=None):
        C.append((ir[1] + ir[2]))
    B.append({"method": "5- itertuples (name=None)", "time": time.time()-A})

    C = []
    A = time.time()
    for ir in t.itertuples():
        C.append((ir[1] + ir[2]))
    B.append({"method": "6- itertuples", "time": time.time()-A})

    C = []
    A = time.time()
    for r in t.to_dict("records"):
        C.append((r["a"] + r["b"]))
    B.append({"method": "7- to_dict('records')", "time": time.time()-A})

print(f'Python {sys.version} on {sys.platform}')
print(f"Pandas version {pd.__version__}")
print(pd.DataFrame(B).groupby("method").agg(["mean", "std"]).xs("time", axis=1).sort_values("mean"))
```

After running the code a few times, the output usually looks something like this:

```
Python 3.10.5 (tags/v3.10.5:f377153, Jun  6 2022, 16:14:13) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Pandas version 1.4.3
                               mean       std
method                                       
1- vectorizing + to_numpy  0.000381  0.000491
2- vectorizing             0.000440  0.000501
3- zip + to_dict('list')   0.002060  0.000865
4- zip                     0.003218  0.001403
5- itertuples (name=None)  0.004189  0.001836
6- itertuples              0.014681  0.053663
7- to_dict('records')      0.024646  0.044051
```

I don't know why sometimes the output is so different from the above. Maybe the CPU is busy while one of the methods is running. I'd appreciate it if someone could write better code to have more stable results (perhaps multiprocessing)

And the main question is: **Is there any method faster than `1- vectorizing + to_numpy`?**

Comment: "I don't know why sometimes the output is so different from the above." - so different, how different are they?

Comment: You're measuring times that might be shorter than a typical thread scheduling time slice. Multiprocessing will not make the results more stable, in contrary. I think it's time for you to understand how the OS and the CPU work together to get things done in order to be able to interpret the results and the variation. You also need to understand TurboBoost, Caches and Hyperthreading.

Comment: Although as I said, most implementations have the same result as I show in my question, the order of the methods in some experiments is changed, and strange results are obtained. For example, sometimes the `to_dict` method is ranked first or second when we all know it is the slowest method in the test.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I've some information on this, but I can't implement it. Could you please write a sample code in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

Your comparison is not fair, consider 2 cases

```
A = time.time()
C = (t['a'] + t['b']).tolist()
B.append({"method": "2- vectorizing", "time": time.time()-A})
```

and

```
C = []
A = time.time()
for ir in t.itertuples():
    C.append((ir[1] + ir[2]))
B.append({"method": "5- itertuples", "time": time.time()-A})
```

Observe that 2nd beyond iteration also use `.append` method of list `C`, this is one of operations which [wiki python TimeComplexity article](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) describe as

> These operations rely on the "Amortized" part of "Amortized Worst
> Case". Individual actions may take surprisingly long, depending on the
> history of the container.

More fair comparison would to be use list comprehension, as follows

```
A = time.time()
C = [ir[1]+ir[2] for ir in t.itertuples()]
B.append({"method": "5- itertuples", "time": time.time()-A})
```

This also pertains to other cases where append is used. You are also ignoring existence of [`pandas.DataFrame.iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) for unknown reasons.

Comment: I just tested your suggestion for `itertuples` and the results did not change. As for `iterrows` (and `iteritems` too) I ignored them because they are known as the slowest methods for iterating dataframes.